# Can't execute commit to svn as root folder is forbidden

Tags: svn, commit, jenkins

I'm trying to execute post build `svn commit` command in Jenkins.

I have access to `http://myrepo.com/myProject ...` but I haven't to `http://myrepo.com/` (the access is forbidden). As a result, when I commit I'm getting the following error:

```
svn commit --message "Build #xx" myfile --non-interactive

svn: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: OPTIONS of 'http://myrepo.com/myProject/myfile': authorization failed: Could not
authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (http://myrepo.com)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run svn from the command line, you do not have access to the
credentials stored in Jenkins.

The easiest way to make svn work from the command line is to provide the
`--username` and `--password` parameters to svn in your build script.

You can also run svn as the Jenkins user and let it store the authentication
in the Jenkins user's home directory. You'll have to set up the authentication
yourself on each node where you need to perform commits. And it's tedious to
maintain if your SSL certificate or password changes periodically. But it does
keep usernames, passwords out of the build scripts.

Perhaps a plugin like [SVN Publisher](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SVN+Publisher) can help with what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. 1) your way works fine. 2) I didn't understand why it doesn't work only in command line? (I tried such command in windows cmd and it works (before I've logged in via tortouiseSVN). 3) Can you describe (or give link about certificates for Jenkins\SVN) more detail? 4) Can you explain plz how SVN Publisher plugin can help me? Thanks in advice.

Comment: in addition to my previous comment: our SVN server doesn't support https connection

Comment: The reason it works for you on the command line is that it's running in your own account. When Jenkins is running the command, it's running as a different user, so your credentials won't be visible.  You can use the `runas` command on Windows to see the effect of this.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So, left only one question.. how can I automatize it ... for the first I don't want to show my credentials .... and for the second I don't want to copy-paste them on each project .. especially if they are using the same svn-repo

Comment: @davs, on your build machine, as the Jenkins user, you can run `svn ls http://myrepo.com/myProject` (and say yes if svn asks whether it should store the password). This will store the credentials in the Jenkins "home" directory so you don't have enter them in every build command.

Comment: Thanks all! I've just added %JENKINS_HOME%\jobs\myproject\subversion.credentials to %USER_HOME%\.jenkins\jobs\myproject\ and it works :):)